# in the same platonic fashion?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> And there was something about this man she instinctively liked, but
>   in the same **platonic fashion** in which he seemed to see her.

source from *Single White Woman*

"in the same platonic fashion" what is in the same with "platonic fashion"?
How can one man see a woman in "platonic fashion"?

Actually, I don't understand this sentence at all.

Comment: I think it is the word "platonic" that you are looking for. Please take a look at this link to get the meaning of it. http://www.yourdictionary.com/platonic
It expresses about a relationship without sexual activity.
And "fashion" here just means the way he seemed to see her, which is the same way she seemed to see him -- in a platonic way.

Comment: @holydragon, Acutally, It's easy to find and figure out "platonic" as I just need to look up it in English-Chinese dictionary. And I have done it.
As Michael Rybkin said, "fashion" in here more confused me than "platonic" :)

Comment: Finally, I understand it, With the help of Michael Rybkin. In this sentence, the most confused me is neither "polatonic" nor "fashion". It's "in the same", at first, I didn't know which in the same with which. Then, I thought it was "he liked her in the way same with her liked him". But all are wrong. It's she liked him in a way in the same with platonic way.

Comment: Next time, please try to do a better job of explaining what you understand and what you don’t understand **in your question itself**, rather than in the comments below your question.

Comment: @J.R. I have explained. And sometimes, I can't understand the entire sentence, and when I finally understand it, I just know which is the most confused me.

Comment: That’s fine. But I’m just pointing out that, the way you initially asked the question, no one knows if you don’t understand _platonic_, or maybe _fashion_, or maybe _platonic fashion_. If  you can do a better job of pinpointing the confusion, the community can do a better job of giving you a helpful answer. But I understand that sometimes this can be difficult to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The noun *fashion* as used in your sentence means *way* or *manner*. It doesn't mean style or clothing. *Platonic* means *intimate and affectionate but not sexual*. It comes from the expression [**Platonic love**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_love) (a type of love that is not sexual in nature). So, what this sentence is saying is that the man and the woman liked each other, but not in a sexual kind of way as you would normally expect since they are two people of opposite genders. In other words, they did not sleep with each other. Let's do a little paraphrasing:

> And there was something about this man she instinctively liked, but in the same **nonsexual way** in which he seemed to see her.

Comment: "In the same way" means "He instictively liked her"?

Comment: *in the same way* means *done in the same manner*. For example, I did it and he did it too in the same way. This means that he did it the exact same way as I did it.

Comment: I almost understand "... she ... liked" is a platonic way, He seemed to like her in that way. But I don't understand why it uses a "but" ("but in the same platonic ....")

Comment: The conjunction *but* is used there for a contrast because when you say a woman likes a man, most people think romantic love. So, you need to tell your readers that the kind of love she felt for the man was not your typical, sexually-oriented love, BUT it was Platonic love. So, she liked him, but not in the way a man and a woman would normally like each other (think sex). Do you understand it better now?

Comment: ooohhhhh, I see!!!!! "In the same" means "she liked him" in the same way with the platonic way. and the "but" is understandable.
Thank you very much!